# Implementing an Identity Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, wif

I have implemented App Fabric Labs' mechanism for authentication into my MVC3 app so now I can log in with Facebook, Google, Yahoo and LiveID.  yea!!

now, what if a user doesn't want to use any of those systems?  I need to provide "traditional" signup forms.  I'm thinking that calls for implementing an identity provider so my app can be left unmodified.

any templates/projects out there all ready for use?

thx - e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WIF SDK comes with a few project templates: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4451

To use them you have to start a new "Website" (not "Project") in Visual Studio: `File -> New... -> Website`

The "ASP.NET Security Token Web Site" template is what you want.

For a more complex STS solution I recommend you to have a look at http://identityserver.codeplex.com/.